# how to use toggle button instead of checkbox using jquery UI in jqGrid

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, toolbar

Code below from other stackoverflow answer is used in jqGrid to implement checkbox using jquery UI in jqGrid top toolbar. This is used to toggle autoedit variable true - false states.

Checkbox caption is too wide for toolbar. How to change checkbox to toolbar button with two states which reflect `autoedit` true/false values (checked and unchecked states). Instead of check mark similar button should appear in pressed or checked state and in regular/unchecked state if clicked again. 
Pure checkmark without caption cannot used since there should be some visual glue instead of checkbox rectangle if tolbar contains more than one such checkbox to distinguish them visually.

```
var autoedit=false;       
$("#grid_toppager_left table.navtable tbody tr").append(
    '<td><div><label><input class="ui-pg-div" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" ' +
        (autoedit ? 'checked ' : '') +
        'id="AutoEdit" />Checbox caption which should appear as top toolbar button tooltip' +
        '</label></div></td>');
$("#AutoEdit").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        autoedit = true;
        $("#AutoEdit").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        autoedit = false;
        $("#AutoEdit").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find your question very interesting. So I made some demos which shows how to implement "toggle" buttons in the navigator bar of jqGrid. In all demos I used top toolbar.

I decide to use [jQuery UI Button](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button) widget. It allows different kind of buttons one from there, the "toggle" button we need. The buttons can be just a text, just an icon or be combination of the text and up to two icons (one icon before the text and another after the text). As the result one can create toolbars like the following:

[image] and [image] in the "checked" state,

[image] and [image] in the "checked" state,

[image] and [image] in the "checked" state,

or just icons only like [image] and [image] for the "checked" state.

Because I used the top toolbar I For the implementation I applied the path of some jqGrid CSS which I described [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/missing-css-for-ui-jqgrid-toppager/#p25154):

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div {
    padding: 1px 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-button {
    height: 18px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div span.ui-icon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

The code which add the custom button which you posted I would modified to

```
var autoedit=false;
...
$("#grid_toppager_left table.navtable tbody tr").append(
    '<td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all">' +
        '<div class="ui-pg-div my-nav-checkbox">' +
        '<input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" id="AutoEdit" />' +
        '<label title="Checkx caption which should appear as button tooltip"' +
        ' for="AutoEdit">Autoedit</label></div></td>'
);
$("#AutoEdit").button().click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        autoedit = true;
        alert("Autoedit mode is ON");
    } else {
        autoedit = false;
        alert("Autoedit mode is OFF");
    }
});
```

in case of pure text button with the text "Autoedit". The corresponding additional CSS settings can be

```css
/* some settings to place Button in jqGrid */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 18px
}
/* fixing CSS of jQuery UI Buttons */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox > .ui-button > span.ui-button-text {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1px 2px 1px 2px;
}
```

In case of usage the icon with the text the code will be

```
$("#AutoEdit").button({
    icons: {primary: "ui-icon-mail-closed"}
}).click(function () {
    var iconClass;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        autoedit = true;
        iconClass = "ui-icon-mail-open";
    } else {
        autoedit = false;
        iconClass = "ui-icon-mail-closed";
    }
    $(this).button("option", {icons: {primary: iconClass}});
});
```

To make the button with icon only without the text one need just add `text: false` option in the list of `.button({...})` parameters

```
$("#AutoEdit").button({
    text: false,
    icons: {primary: "ui-icon-mail-closed"}
}).click(function () {
...
```

In both cases the following CSS can be used

```css
/* some settings to place Button in jqGrid */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 18px
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox > input {
    padding: 1px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox > label {
    margin: 0px;
}
/* fixing CSS of jQuery UI Buttons */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox > .ui-button > span.ui-button-text {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1px 2px 1px 16px;
}
.ui-button-icon-only {
    width: 16px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox > .ui-button > span.ui-button-icon-primary {
    margin: -8px 0px 0px -8px;
}
```

For different demos you can find here:

- [icon only "toggle" button](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavGridCheckboxButton4.htm)
- [text only "toggle" button](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavGridCheckboxButton1.htm)
- ["toggle" button with the icon and the text](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavGridCheckboxButton3.htm)
- ["toggle" button with the text and two icons](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavGridCheckboxButton2.htm)

To have the border over the button only on hovering you can change the CSS for the `.my-nav-checkbox > label` to

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox > label {
    margin: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox:hover > label {
    margin: 0px;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

As the result you will have (see [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavGridCheckboxButton4_.htm)):

- standard state button [image]
- hover state of the button [image]
- standard state "checked" button [image]
- hover state of the "checked" button [image]

Comment: Thank you very much. In first demo tooltip `Checkx caption which should appear as button tooltip` does not appear if mouse is hover button

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! The problem with the tooltip is very easy. One should just move `title` attribute from `<td>` to `<lable>`. I modified the demos and the code from the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Push button has always border so it is different from other buttons. How to remove push button border especially in unchecked state so it looks like other buttons?

Comment: @Andrus: CSSs from my answer are my suggestions. You can change ther like you as need. For example to remove border you can set `border: 0px;` of the `<label>`: `.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .my-nav-checkbox > label { margin: 0px; border: 0px; }`. You can also change the position of the icon and so on. Just try to change constants in the CSS and you will see the results of the changes.

Comment: @Andrus: See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavGridCheckboxButton4_.htm) which has border over the icon only on hovering.

Comment: @Andrus: I appended the answer with the description of the demo.

Comment: thank you. autoedit value is saved in cookie. How to set button to checked state if autoedit is true after page is loaded? I added autoedit=true but button is still in unchecked state.

Comment: Using `'<input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" id="AutoEdit" '+(autoedit ? 'checked ' : '')+'/>'` seems to show checked state if autoedit is true

Comment: @Andrus: To set button state you can either create `<input>` element with `checked="checked"` attribute or use jQuery UI Button API to change the button state: `$("#AutoEdit").prop("checked", true).button("refresh");`. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/NavGridCheckboxButton4_checked.htm)

Comment: After moving those styles to site.css file checkbox button width increases a lot. Should those styles specified in site.master always or is it possible to move them them to site.css ?

Comment: If checkbox is unchecked, its background is darker than in other buttons which have toolbar background. How to make its background  same as in other buttons, i.e equal to toolbar backgound after clicking checked state button ?

Comment: moving site.css load after ui.jqgrid.css seems to fix button width issue. So only dark background on checked button click issue remains

Comment: @Andrus: If you overwrite some CSS styles it's very important to place CSS definition on the correct place in the list of the loaded CSS on the page. The last definition overwrite or modified the previous one. So you should just be careful with the **order** of included CSS files or place some definition on the master page.